# How to make items reorderable *using touch* in an UWP 10.0 XAML/C# project

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-10, uwp

According to the example on [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems.aspx) page, the following code would enable reordering of the items in a ListView. Actually it does, but only using the mouse. If I put the window on my touchscreen and touch the items, it'll show the 'scroll failed' animation (move vertically then pop back) and items won't reorder. Any suggestions?

```
<ListView CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate><TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/></DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>One</x:String>
    <x:String>Two</x:String>
    <x:String>Three</x:String>
    <x:String>Four</x:String>
</ListView>
```

This is all in an UWP 10.0 project (frameworks: uap10.0), to be specific.

I'd hope this to work without having to write drag and drop code.

Answer (score 0):

Spent an hour on this before moving on, ending up [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CollectionViewSourceIsCrazyUsefulForBindingToFilteredObservableCollectionsOnWindowsPhone8.aspx) three hours later trying to solve yet another problem.

> Tap & hold, then drag to reorder

Scott uses hamburgers for grips...good choice. The tip is something static has got to be in the list to be reordered, to be able to 'grab' the item or the reordering might not work because gestures are being handled to do something else. My list was short but had checkboxes in it which would get checked/unchecked and you can't reorder after that. In the image, the list is longer than the screen. Once it starts scrolling you can't reorder anymore.

Seems I had been too hasty with my fingers too. I didn't seem to be able to reorder even if no checkboxes changed state or with the exact code from the question, containing only strings.

Quite happy with the amount of code this required ;)

[image: Stolen from Scott Hanselmans Blog]